# multiply all the columns with a constant

Tags: linux, awk

How can I multiply a file with upto 25 (This number varies) columns with a constant number, and print out results with 3 decimals.

I have tried

```
awk '{for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) printf "%.3f", $i*1000}' combined.txt >> combined1.txt
```

This just prints all the results in 1st column. there is only one large column with all the calculated values. How can I make it follow the same number of rows and columns as input?

Data file example:

```
 0   8.4937e-005   0.0000e+000   -5.0721e-006   1.6484e-006   -1.7687e-006   1.8932e-006  3.9437e-007   
 1   8.5234e-005   0.0000e+000   -5.1815e-006   1.6891e-006   -1.8060e-006   1.9073e-006  3.9212e-007   
 2   9.5818e-005   0.0000e+000   -5.9843e-006   1.9090e-006   -2.0271e-006   1.9332e-006  4.6143e-007   
 3   1.0172e-004   0.0000e+000   -7.3778e-006   2.5445e-006   -2.3937e-006   1.9825e-006  4.4063e-007
```

Expected results

```
0   0.0849  0.0000  -0.0051 0.0016  -0.0018 0.0019  0.0004
1   0.0852  0.0000  -0.0052 0.0017  -0.0018 0.0019  0.0004
2   0.0958  0.0000  -0.0060 0.0019  -0.0020 0.0019  0.0005
3   0.1017  0.0000  -0.0074 0.0025  -0.0024 0.0020  0.0004
4   0.1051  0.0000  -0.0087 0.0030  -0.0022 0.0018  0.0005
```

I would really appreciate any advice!

Comment: Is the first column shown (0,1,2,3...) part of the data? If so, you need to start from `$2`, not `$1`. Also, your output has 4 decimal places, so you need `%.4f` not `%.3f`

Comment: The reason your second attempt only produces one number is that `I` is not the same as `i`. Even if you fixed that, `FS=,` tells awk to delimit fields by commas. Your sample data has no commas, so awk will treat the entire line as a single field. When it does `$i*1000`, awk will attempt convert the line into a number (by reading as much as it can - ie. until the first whitespace - possibly implemented using the C function `strtod`).

Comment: @jhnc Thanks I will update the `%.4f` but still the output has only one big column with all the calculated values. How can I get the output to be columnized as input as well. Also thanks for highlighting the I. I have made some changes to my question.

Comment: What's your input field separator?

Comment: please update the question with the a textual copy of the expected output (as opposed to the current image)

Comment: In the future, realize that we don't really need to see 20x20 matrix of data to help you solve your problem.(Happily, you included expected output, but that is too much too (-;!) ...  If the number of columns in input will vary, then 2 lines, with different number of columns is all that is needed. Also, 3-4 columns is probably is enough too. Glad you got some help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
awk '{
    printf "%3d", $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%9.4f", $i*1000
    print ""
}' file
```

Comment: Where is the delimiter between the columns? The code in the question implies that it should be comma-separated.

Comment: @Barmar Neither the code in the question nor the sample data implies comma-separated columns.

Comment: The question has been edited. The original code included `FS=, OFS=,`

Answer (score 4):

Issues with OP's current code:

- does not print the 1st column
- does not provide a separator between columns
- does not terminate each line of output with a `\n`

One idea for modifying OP's current code to address these issues:

```
awk '
{ printf "%s",$1                          # print 1st column
  for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
      printf "%s%.4f", OFS, $i*1000       # add separator (OFS) between columns
  print ""                                # terminate output line with a \n
}
' combined.txt
```

A variation using `sprintf` to update the columns before printing:

```
awk '
{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)  
      $i = sprintf("%.4f",$i*1000)        # update column #i
}
1                                         # print current line
' combined.txt
```

Both of these generate:

```
0 0.0849 0.0000 -0.0051 0.0016 -0.0018 0.0019 0.0004
1 0.0852 0.0000 -0.0052 0.0017 -0.0018 0.0019 0.0004
2 0.0958 0.0000 -0.0060 0.0019 -0.0020 0.0019 0.0005
3 0.1017 0.0000 -0.0074 0.0025 -0.0024 0.0020 0.0004
4 0.1051 0.0000 -0.0087 0.0030 -0.0022 0.0018 0.0005
5 0.1065 0.0000 -0.0095 0.0029 -0.0015 0.0014 0.0005
6 0.1064 0.0000 -0.0095 0.0024 -0.0006 0.0010 0.0005
7 0.1056 0.0000 -0.0089 0.0017 0.0003 0.0006 0.0005
8 0.1048 0.0000 -0.0078 0.0012 0.0011 0.0004 0.0004
9 0.1045 0.0000 -0.0062 0.0009 0.0015 0.0002 0.0003
10 0.1048 0.0000 -0.0045 0.0007 0.0014 -0.0001 -0.0001
11 0.1057 0.0000 -0.0031 0.0004 0.0006 -0.0005 -0.0006
12 0.1070 0.0000 -0.0022 -0.0000 -0.0009 -0.0008 -0.0010
13 0.1086 0.0000 -0.0019 -0.0003 -0.0025 -0.0009 -0.0011
14 0.1105 0.0000 -0.0019 -0.0005 -0.0036 -0.0010 -0.0007
15 0.1124 0.0000 -0.0022 -0.0006 -0.0039 -0.0012 -0.0002
16 0.1145 0.0000 -0.0025 -0.0005 -0.0035 -0.0014 0.0001
17 0.1165 0.0000 -0.0027 -0.0003 -0.0027 -0.0015 0.0003
18 0.1184 0.0000 -0.0026 0.0000 -0.0019 -0.0015 0.0004
19 0.1201 0.0000 -0.0022 0.0003 -0.0012 -0.0015 0.0004
20 0.1216 0.0000 -0.0017 0.0004 -0.0008 -0.0017 0.0003
21 0.1229 0.0000 -0.0011 0.0004 -0.0006 -0.0020 0.0002
22 0.1240 0.0000 -0.0004 0.0001 -0.0005 -0.0023 -0.0001
23 0.1251 0.0000 0.0004 -0.0002 -0.0006 -0.0025 -0.0003
24 0.1261 0.0000 0.0013 -0.0006 -0.0006 -0.0026 -0.0005
25 0.1270 0.0000 0.0025 -0.0009 -0.0007 -0.0024 -0.0005
26 0.1277 0.0000 0.0038 -0.0012 -0.0009 -0.0022 -0.0004
27 0.1280 0.0000 0.0055 -0.0015 -0.0012 -0.0018 -0.0001
28 0.1276 0.0000 0.0079 -0.0021 -0.0019 -0.0015 0.0003
29 0.1259 0.0000 0.0112 -0.0031 -0.0026 -0.0013 0.0008
30 0.1255 0.0000 0.0118 -0.0033 -0.0028 -0.0012 0.0009
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` doesn't use `OFS`. Put the delimiter after `%.3f` in the format string.

```
awk -F',' '{for ( i=1; i<NF; i++ ) printf "%.3f,", $i*1000; printf "%.3f\n", $NF*1000}' combined.txt >> combined1.txt
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Only gave output of just one column.

Comment: @ash : it didn't work cuz @Barmar needs to add `{ … }` surrounding all the `printf` to delineate the space where the `for` loop operates upon

Comment: Without `{}` it's just the first `printf` statement.